# What is the closest equivalent to the abidw utility for OS X

Tags: macos, shared-libraries, abi, dwarf, mach

The [abidw utility](https://sourceware.org/libabigail/manual/abidw.html) produces an XML document describing the ABI of a given ELF shared library, which makes it very useful when doing library development. Unfortunately, it is ELF only.

Is anyone aware of a utility to obtain the same sort of information about MACH-O dylibs? For the particular application I have in mind, I don't much care about the XML'ness of the output (I'm MD5'ing the abidw output anyway), but I do care that I get different output if a re-linked dylib exposes a new ABI, and, more importantly, that I get the same output if the ABI hasn't changed.

Are there any utilities for extracting an ABI definition or hash from a dylib on OS X?